# Excel File and Sheet Location

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd, import-from-excel

I have a list of excel files and their corresponding sheet number. I need python to go to those sheets and find out the cell location for a particular content. Thanks to "alecxe", I used the following code and it worked well.

```
import xlrd
value = 'Avg.'
fn = ('C:/ab1.xls', 'C:/ab2.xls','C:/ab3.xls','C:/ab4.xls','C:/ab5.xls',)
sn = ('505840', '505608', '430645', '505464', '505084')
for name, sheet_name in zip(fn, sn):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value:
                print row, column
```

Later I wanted to make changes and instead of writing down the filename and sheetnumber, I wanted python to grab them from an excel sheet. But the program is not printing anything. Can anyone show me where I made the mistake? Highly appreciate your comment!

```
import xlrd
import glob
import os
value = 'Avg.'
sheetnumber = []
filename = []
xlfile = "C:\\Users\\tsengineer\\Desktop\\Joydip Trial\\Simple.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    value = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 17))
    filename.append(value)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    value = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 15))
    sheetnumber.append(value)
fn = tuple(filename)
sn = tuple(sheetnumber)
for name, sheet_name in zip(fn, sn):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value:
                print row, column
```

Definitely for some reasons, the loop is not working as I am getting two empty lists as output. Any thoughts?

```
import xlrd
value = 'Avg.'
sheetnumber = []
filename = []
rowlist = []
columnlist = []
xlfile = "C:/Users/Joyd/Desktop/Experiment/Simple_1.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlfile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    value = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 17))
    filename.append(value)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    value = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 15))
    sheetnumber.append(value)
fn = tuple(filename)
sn = tuple(sheetnumber)
for fname, sname in zip(fn, sn):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sname)
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value:
                rowlist.append(row)
                columnlist.append(column)
print rowlist
print columnlist
```

Comment: Are you sure columns are 17 and 15? (don't forget that index start with 0 - try 16 and 14).

Comment: Yes, the columns are correct. I have checked by print fn and print sn . Whenever I give the direct link, it works. But it does not work when I am importing them from the excel file. No idea why this is happening.

Comment: Debug it a bit, put a print statement inside the `for name, sheet_name in zip(fn, sn)` loop, see if it at least opens up the excel files.

Comment: used append function to see if the loop was working. As I am getting two empty lists, definitely something is not right. Any thoughts?

Comment: When I remove value = 'Avg.' and replace if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value: with if sheet.cell(row,column).value == 'Avg': it works :)